# how to customize ionic placeholder icon

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionicons

I have a text input for searching for products on one page with a magnifying glass placeholder icon.  On a different page i have a text input specifically to receive barcode data.

I would like to differentiate these by using a barcode icon as the placeholder icon however the placeholder icons seem to be specifically using the Ionicon font instead of icons defined in CSS or something else.

Is there a way to define a custom icon that can be used as a placeholder icon?

I have custom tab icons defined like this:

```
.tabs .tab-item .icon.gmBagOn {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background-image: url('../img/ic_shop_white_24px.svg');
  background-size: contain;
}
```

I can reference these in the code like this:
`<ion-tab title="Lookup" ui-sref="tab.lookup" icon-off="gmSearchOff" icon-on="gmSearchOn">`

I tried defining it as just the icon name `.icon.barcode` and referencing it like:

```
<form class="padding" ng-submit="submit(searchUPC)">
   <label class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-barcode"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder='' ng-model="inputs.textbox">
   </label>
</form>
```

However this creates an empty placeholder.  Also while trying to change the color of the place holder icon I found that it takes on the placeholder text color or the textbox fill color which makes me think it is actually using the font definition rather then an icon definition.

Comment: Show some of your code; what have you tried so far?